# Create custom properties for JMS Queue

Tags: java, jboss, jakarta-ee, jms, ejb-3.0

I am using Jboss.x , EJB3.0.

I have two JMS queues.
"A" queue and "Error" Que.

A que has a retry mechanism, so after 3 retries, the MSG will be deliver to an error queue automatically, and there  mdb will listen.

I want to add to the MSG which will be delivered to the error Que, an extra property which I will define. (Ofcourse I cant add to the body an extra line, since I have rollbacks, and each time a rollback is being executed, the body will rollback also)

So I read little in the net, and I got that I can use the header for this purpose(roll backs wont affect it). in order to user the header for my custom property I must create
JMSPropertyType and add to it the header. I didn't find info how to do it, mybe anyone could show me, or maybe there is another way of doing this?

thanks,
ray.

Answer (score 0):

Transactional retry limits and poison message queues (your error queue) are vendor-specific features.  They're not in the JMS spec.  You should read your vendor documentation (JBOSS, apparently) for any details.

I'm skeptical that a failing receiver could add a property to a message as you ask.  Your vendor might implicitly add some properties itself.  I think I've seen a case (BEA JMS?) where they add some vendor-specific property with the failed delivery attempt count.

Comment: I can get the failed delivery attempt count from header properties.. but how would I new propert for my own use?

Comment: the failing receiver you are talking about, is MDB which get the message.

Comment: Like I said, I'm skeptical that the message receiver (MDB) can add properties.  I believe adding message properties is something a sender can do, not a receiver.  So in other words, you should try to find another way to accomplish what you're doing.